# iTunes Connect confusion

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

1) In my iTunes connect account there is a Support URL (required) and a Marketing URL (optional). If you look at any app's App store page there it says Developer Website. So is the developer website the same as iTunes connect Support URL or Marketing URL?

2) Also, I want to do manual release to get promo codes for review sites and others. So if I were to set app for review in iTunes Connect, how far do I set the "Availability date" in the "Pricing tab" in the future? How long is a review if approved?

3) Also, lets say it's approved and I set the future date to September 1st for example for manual release. Would Apple instantly upload my App into the App store September 1st or would I have to confirm something first or is there more to it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Developer Web site will be same as support URL.

2) As per my knowledge, if you use promo code then you may not post review for it.

3) Apple will instantly publish your app on availability date.

Comment: I know about the promo codes and no reviews but I was asking how long does Apple review process take? I would set a fake date out first but don't know how far to set it out.